# How to use C++20 concepts to check some constraints in the template itself

Tags: c++, oop, c++20, c++-concepts

Sorry for the ambiguous title, I couldn't find the right words to phrase it.
I'm trying to force a class to define some functions/operators to be correct. for example `ForwardIterator` is required to have some operators otherwise I should get a compiler error. I have asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65447631/implementing-an-abstract-class-as-a-interface-for-other-classes-without-vtable-o) and I was given a method with inheritance, it works perfectly but C++20 concepts seem to be more intuitive and give better errors.
The initial idea is:

```
template <typename T> concept is_ForwardIterator= requires(T x, T y)
{
    x == y;
};
template <typename T>
requires  is_ForwardIterator<T>
struct ForwardIterator {
};
```

Then whenever I want to implement a forward iterator I inherit from `ForwardIterator`:

```
struct MyCustomIterator
   : public ForwardIterator <MyCustomIterator> 
{
  bool operator ==(const MyCustomIterator& other) const;
};
```

But the compiler keeps complaining that `MyCustomIterator` doesn't satisfy the requirement:

```
error: constraints not satisfied for class template 'ForwardIterator' [with T = MyCustomIterator]
note: because 'MyCustomIterator' does not satisfy 'is_ForwardIterator'
template <typename T> requires is_ForwardIterator<T> struct ForwardIterator {
                               ^
note: because 'x == y' would be invalid: invalid operands to binary expression ('MyCustomIterator' and 'MyCustomIterator')
        x == y;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `ForwardIterator`? Just a way to tag and check the custom type for satisfaction of constraints? And if so, if the type has to opt in to this check, why can't one just static assert on the type after the full class definition? `class MyCustomIterator{}; static_assert(is_ForwardIterator<MyCustomIterator>);`

Comment: Are you aware that the parameter to the `==` overload should be a `const` reference parameter, and not a mutable reference parameter?

Comment: It's a bit odd to add constraints on a class in it's definition. Usually you would want to check the constraints when the class is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CRTP, derived class in incomplete, so checking its property is not possible.

One way to check interface with traits/concept is simply `static_assert` after the class:

```
template <typename T> concept is_ForwardIterator= requires(T x, T y)
{
    x == y;
    // ...
};

struct MyCustomIterator
{
    bool operator ==(const MyCustomIterator& other) const;
    // ...
};
static_assert(is_ForwardIterator<MyCustomIterator>);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you try to use the CRTP, during the compilation of the base class template, the derived class is *incomplete*. As such, asking most questions about its behavior is impossible. This includes most of the reasons to use a concept.

What you're trying to do cannot reasonably be done that way. You may need a traits class or something, depending on what your goal is.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that where the constraint on `ForwardIterator` is specified, the class `T` (that is, `MyCustomIterator`) is incomplete - it exists as a class name only.

You need to delay checking of the constraint until after `MyCustomIterator` is complete. One way to do this is a [constraint on the *destructor* of `ForwardIterator`](https://godbolt.org/z/3x47dn):

```
template <typename T>
struct ForwardIterator {
    ~ForwardIterator() requires is_ForwardIterator<T> {}
};
```

The only problem here is that this will not be checked until there is a reason to instantiate the destructor `~ForwardIterator`, i.e. if you do not actually instantiate a `MyCustomIterator` object it will not be checked. But this should not be a problem in practice.